# ArcPy Layer export include joined table

Tags: arcpy

How do I include the joined table when exporting a layer from an MXD using ArcPY.

I am using doing this:

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(layer.dataSource, outLocation, 
                                                outFeatureClass)
```

which does not include the joined information

Comment: Looks like I should use the CopyFeatures method.

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layer, outLocation + "\\" + outFeatureClass)

Comment: Feel free to post your working solution as an answer.

Comment: Don't you also need to MakeFeatureLayer and AddJoin first?

Comment: Also, JoinField will permanently join a table, no need to save to another feature class.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/126489/115 from the duplicate provides the solution